# Get Model where relationship = id

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3

Would love to know how other people are achieving the following?

Tables:

```
teams 
teams_users (pivot many teams, many users)
users
```

What i am trying to achieve

```
$teams->user->where('user_id', $id)->get();
```

however i am having to run a loop, and create another method on the team model to pluck(id, name)

```
// foreach ($teams as $team) {
//     # code...
//     dump($team->getUserIdsAttribute());
// }
```

Do you know a better way?

Answer (score 10):

If you are trying to get all teams with a specific a user id. Try

```
$teams = Team::with(['users' => function ($query) use ($id) {
    $query->where('id', '=', $id);
}])->get();
```

Or through the user

```
$user = User::with('teams')->find($id);
```

This is assuming you already defined the `belongsToMany()` relationship in each model.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you will like to do it in the more traditional way

```
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
    $team = Team::whereHas('user',function(Builder $query) use ($id){
        $query->where( 'user_id' , $id );
    })->get();
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped me a lot! The other answer here that suggess using `with` won't actually quite solve the problem, because when the inner query doesn't match, the relation is just empty, hence the Team that the User is not on is still present in the collection.